# How to link a line in OneNote to an existing Outlook task?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

In OneNote I know how to create a new Outlook task which is linked to a OneNote line. (e.g. switch to OneNote, press Ctrl+Shift+1 task which is due today is created).

Is it way to create a link to **existing** Outlook task or to existing (flagged) mail message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Office 2010, I Created a new task in outlook, and saved it.

I opened it back up.

I clicked "Onenote" under the 'task' ribbon panel. (see image)

It prompted me with a dialog for what page to send the task to.

The task flag appeared on that page as if I had created the task directly inside of Onenote.

[image: Send to Onenote Button]

Comment: I didn't know you could do this till I tried.  Glad they didn't overlook this feature.

Comment: I knew about this, but the problem is that when I send an Outlook task to OneNote, the Outlook task is simply pasted into OneNote without any dynamic linking.  As such, changes to the task performed in OneNote do not propagate back to Outlook.